# Get regex group with fuzziness

Tags: python, regex, string, fuzzy-search

I have a very big list of words (around 200k):

```
["cat", "the dog", "elephant", "the angry tiger"]
```

I created this regex, with fuzziness :

```
regex = "(cat){e<3}|(the dog){e<3}|(elephant){e<3}|(the angry tiger){e<3}"
```

I have input sentences :

```
sentence1 = "The doog is running in the field"
sentence2 = "The elephent and the kat"
...
```

What I want to get is this :

```
res1 = ["the dog"]
res2 = ["elephant", "cat"]
```

I tried this for example:

```
re.findall(regex, sentence2, flags=re.IGNORECASE|re.UNICODE)
```

But this outputs me :

```
["elephent", "kat"]
```

Any idea how to get the right answer with corrected words ? What I want is to get the regex capturing group for each match but I struggle to do so.

Maybe I'm not doing this right and maybe the regex way is not the good one but the `if item in list` with a `for` loop is way too long to execute.

Comment: which version of python are you using? are you using `re` package? or `regex` package?

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre I'm using Python 3.6 and I'm using regex package

Comment: in python 3.4 with `re` package I don't have fuzziness, that"s why

Comment: Do you think you can build an alternation with 200k items?

Comment: you could loop on each word `(cat){e<3}` then ... if there's a match, you know for sure what matched. But it's going to be slower. Maybe with precompiled regexes.

Comment: looking for 2000 words non-fuzzy like a|b|c|d ... already takes forever, it's a linear search, even if it's inside regex.

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte i'm not familiar with alternation, but I will look for it on google :)

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre indeed but the regex module is implemented in C and is way faster than a classical python loop. It takes 2-3 secondes faster and those seconds are really critical for me

Comment: An alternation is the name for `abc|defg|hi|jkl` in a regex pattern.

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte Ok thanks. I built this alternation then, why ?

Comment: I don't think using a simple regex is the way to go. I suggest to read [this page](https://streamhacker.com/2011/10/31/fuzzy-string-matching-python/) for other alternatives.

Comment: stemming and lemmatization may be an interesting approach if it fits your needs.

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte yes i can do that but the sentences are user inputs, so I need to deal with misspellings. Stemming or lemmatizing "kat" won't give me "cat"

Comment: In this case try with soundex.

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte thank you, I will work on that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It can be done by manually constructing the regex and naming the groups:

```
import regex as re

a = ["cat", "the dog", "elephant", "the angry tiger"]
a_dict = { 'g%d' % (i):item for i,item in enumerate(a) } 

regex = "|".join([ r"\b(?<g%d>(%s){e<3})\b" % (i,item) for i,item in enumerate(a) ])

sentence1 = "The doog is running in the field"
sentence2 = "The elephent and the kat"

for match in re.finditer(regex, sentence2, flags=re.IGNORECASE|re.UNICODE):
    for key,value in match.groupdict().items():
        if value is not None:
            print ("%s: %s" % (a_dict.get(key), value))
```

---

```
elephant:  elephent
cat:  kat
```

Comment: I believe OP needs a whole word search. Use `regex = r"\b(?:{})\b".format("|".join([ "(?<g%d>(%s){e<3})" % (i,item) for i,item in enumerate(a) ]))`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Thanks, with `\b` it looks better.

Comment: That's really interesting and it works well, thank you. I was not familiar with naming groups. I validate this answer but if anyone has a faster way of dealing with my problem, please feel free :D

Comment: However, it is better to use a single pair of `\b`s around the whole alternation group, as in my comment.

Comment: @MohamedALANI There is no better way, I think it is the only way with regex. Otherwise, do what Casimir suggests. However, this approach may not work in all cases if there are terms like `the` and `the dog` where `the` should be different.

Comment: There is the trie alternative that can speed up the `finditer`part but getting the capturing group must be much more painful